# PowerShell: Kill and message prompt by window title

Tags: powershell, window, title

Is there a way in powershell to listen for message prompts produced by software that will terminate the message prompt?

For instance, if I am using an application and then it prompts a message for the user to click "OK".  IS there a way I can use PowerShell to find that "window title" to kill that prompt?

Comment: I think you should use AutoIt/AutoHotket for that. The support to manipulate a window depend on what whas used to create it, but I think is very feasible.

Comment: Yes, someone did mention that idea to me. To use AutoIt and then drop down the exe and run it.  Then it will monitor prompts by Windows Title Name and close them.  I was looking for a light and efficient way to do it. I looked into powershell but could not find anything out on Google or Stackoverflow.  If I can't find a way to do it in PowerShell, then I'll download AutoIt.

Comment: You can use the WASP powershell module (google it). I believe there other modules as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this two commands:

```
$TitleToKill = "CMD"

get-process | where-object {$_.MainWindowTitle -eq $TitleToKill} | stop-process
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go with AutoIt.

I noticed AutoIt has an AutoIt Window Info tool that you can hover you mouse over the Message Prompt.  Then the Window Info will give you the Windows Title, Text and CLASS ID if it has one.

Then you can write a simple autoit script that will Wait for the message prompt and close it.

Example Script that I'm using.

```
WinWait("[CLASS:#32770]", "Cannot sign in to Lync because this sign-in address was not found. Please verify the sign-in address and try again. If the problem continues, please contact your support team.", 0)
WinClose( "Lync")
```

WinWait will wait for the prompt with that specific message and close it. Once it performs the action and closes the window.  The EXE will shutdown and stop running, of course unless you program it not to close and loop.